# Linux - Check the makefile options with which the current kernel is built

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make

I remember there is a way(command) to check the makefile(make) options that distribution developers used them to build the kernel of current distribution. Is my memory wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you make the `make` options? The kernel configuration options are certainly captured, but some of the other options passed to the make process are not stored in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To show the compile flags of the running kernel:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Comment: If the distributers included the file...  Also there used to be a kernel option to include the config in the kernel file itself, if that was enabled it would be at /proc/config

Comment: That's right, stilll I can't think of a distro that doesn''t include it nowadays. I think the kernel option you mention is `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`